# EGit and Eclipse modifies .gitignore file but it should not

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I'm using Eclipse and EGit, but Eclipse modifies my *.gitignore* file without me asking to do so. As soon as I open Eclipse the *.gitignore* file is modified.

I've added some folders to *.gitignore* (through EGit) but removed them after, but Eclipse keeps adding removed lines to *.gitignore*.

1. `git checkout .gitignore`, I get the good version of the file
2. Then I go to Eclipse window
3. Then I go back to terminal and issue: `git status`,
4. I can see that .gitignore is now modified.

How can it be?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the modifications are not wanted? The contents of `.gitignore` before and after would also help.

Comment: In what way was it modified?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

By default, EGit automatically adds resources marked as "Derived" to `.gitignore`. A typical example is the `bin` folder in a Java project containing the compiled classes.

You can disable this by going to Window > Preferences > Team > Git > Projects and deselect "Automatically ignore derived resources by adding them to .gitignore".

There was also a bug in EGit where it added entries when the Eclipse model and the filesystem were out-of-sync, see [bug 421610](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421610) (fixed for EGit 3.5).

Comment: I think you're right, by removing my project from eclipse it removed the configuration (derived files selection included)

Comment: I'm seeing this exact symptom with Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2, but I don't find the checkbox you refer to, so I can't disable it.  Is there a property I can edit, or some other way around this?  BTW, thanks for explaining why this is happening.

Comment: @philwalk: It's still at the same location in the Eclipse preferences (just checked).

Comment: For Eclipse 4.4 (Luna), the full path is Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Projects -> "Automatically ignore derived resources by adding them to .gitignore"

Comment: thank you, I was using autoderiv and that meant that "stuff" ended in my .gitignore without reason