# .gitignore file adding "/bin/" each time something changes in the project

Tags: eclipse, git

After any changes to the git repo, the .gitignore file is shown as modified when "git status":

```
modified: .gitignore
modified: someclass.java
```

It simply adds a new line "/bin/", so that after af few commits the .gitignore file looks like this:

```
bin/
/bin/
/bin/
/bin/
```

I am using Eclipse. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using a build tool or any other tool / IDE plugin / ... that could have manipulated the file?

Comment: I am using eclipse, but not any plugins that i know of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect your are using Eclipse, since I had the same problem using Eclipse. If that is the case, EGit modifies .gitignore. You can disable this like this:

- Under the Window menu, select Preferences.
- Version Control (Team) > Git > Projects.
- Deselect "Automatically ignore derived resources by adding them to .gitignore".

[see related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17748223/2082964)

Comment: you're welcome. If your problem is solved, consider marking the answer as correct; so others can see that your problem is solved.