# Eclipse Maven showing multiple paths for the same file

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, multi-module, file-search

Is there any setting in Eclipse to show only the Maven project where the file resides?

I have different Maven projects which are modules of a parent Maven project:

```
projParent
   |-projWeb
   |-projModel
   |-projServices
   |-...
```

If I look for a file using "Open Resource" (using `Ctrl + Shift + r`) in Eclipse, it appears in many projects (E.g.: in projParent and in projWeb).

Is there any way to show only relevant folder where that file is actually resided in?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064796/eclipse-file-search-finds-the-same-file-multiple-times, but the other question has a much better [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15067818/722760) (set folders in parent projects as "derived").

Answer (score 20):

Try defining a [Working Set](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cworkset.htm) that includes only the modules in which you want to search and then use that Working Set in the search.

**EDIT**

Actually I tried it and it just **works perfectly by default in eclipse 4.3 (Kepler)**, only one result is returned for nested projects.

Anyway, here's how to use working set in open resource (the example is not of a resource in a nested module as in this case Kepler don't show duplicate results; so the example is just of two different resources baring the same name in two different modules):

(1) Hit the *ctrl+shift+R* keys. I searched for a resource called `pom.xml`. You can see two results:

[image: open resource no working set]

(2) Press the little downward-pointing arrow on the top right of the window and choose `Select Working Set...`:

[image: open resource select working set]

(3) Check the radio button of `Selected Working Sets` and check the desired projects (in your case the leaf projects):

[image]

(4) And voila, `Open Resource` returns only one result:

[image: open resource after working set is selected]

Comment: I do not want use search open as it is time consuming & it does not make sense using it to open file .. i would rather visually distinguish the path of the file

Comment: @user593029 you only need to choose in the `Open Resource` window the Working Set once and it'll be used each time you use it for search, it's not "open search".

Comment: @user593029 I hope the snapshots are right, I can't see them in stack myself (imgur is blocked here...).

Comment: I think probably working set is the only option i have tried this earlier but only issue is you have to deselect everytime.. however it is weird that eclipse shows the parent & other modules as path for the same file. I was though looking for other setting that can help show only path where in the file actually resides.

Answer (score 16):

You are probably talking about a kind of duplication between parent project and its sub-modules. In the latest version of Eclipse (from 3.6 maybe and sure from 3.7) there is a new option

> Menu Windows >
>
> ```
> Item Preferences >
>
>     Tree item Maven >
>
>        Option : Hide folders of physically nested modules
> ```

This would not work on a existing project. You must delete them (logically) and re-import them

Comment: It is not working by checking above option.. for example if webservice.java is checked in projservice maven project & projparent is parent maven project of projservice. What I see on openning resources is /projservice/webservice.java & /projparent/projservice/webservice.java... not sure how to get rid of redudant /projparent/projservice/webservice.java entry into open resouces.. I do not want use search open as it is time consuming & it does not make sense using it to open file .. i would rather visually distinguish the path of the file

Comment: A similar option is available in Kepler (4.3) but it doesn't work for me.  You can access it through the preferences:

In the Maven tab, you can check off "Hide folders of physically nested modules (experimental)"

Comment: As I said, you MUST delete and re-import them activate this feature, but it could still not work ... ah ... IntelliJ Idea is quite better for that !

Comment: Works when re-importing all projects as "Existing Maven projects"

Comment: In Eclipse Mars the feature is still marked as "Experimental".

Comment: Really ? Indeed, last time I imported a maven project into Eclipse Mars 1, then it automatically found the appropriate structure, hiding nested directories and showing the rights modules.

Comment: There's a catch: On Eclipse Oxygen, it doesn't work for me if I import the projects with 'Open project from filesystem'. But it works fine using File -> Import ... -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and what worked for me was to select `Filter Duplicated Resources` in the `Open Resource` dialog:

[image: Open menu]
[image: Enable filter]

Another (unrelated) useful feature is to hide submodule-folders from the parent-project in the package explorer.
This can be done by using the `Maven modules` filter in the menu of the package explorer:
[image: Enable maven modules filter]

Tested with Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12.0)