# Hide Maven projects in Eclipse Package Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I import a project into Eclipse using "Existing Maven Project" I can see the Maven project and all sub-projects in the Package Explorer like this:

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

The project has a structure like this:

```
karaf-tutorial-cxf\
    \personservice-parent
       \psersonservice-proxy
       \psersonservice-server
       \psersonservice-webui 
        ...
```

Two questions:

(1) Is it possible automatically hide Maven projects in the Package Explorer and only show Java projects? (in my example hide karaf-tutorial-cxf and personservice-parent)

(2) When I do a text search using "File / Search / Workspace" I get multiple hits for the same source file. One for the Java file, one from it's Maven parent (personservice-parent) and one from the parents parent (karaf-tutorial-cxf). Is it possible to only show one hit (the one from the Java file)?

Answer (score 0):

First answer,

> Hide folders from nested maven project option is available as experimental feature in eclipse. It is available while importing maven project. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797438/eclipse-maven-showing-multiple-path-for-same-file) option for more details

Second answer

> you can use open type `CTRL+T` for opening correct java file. it will now show you multiple files from different sources.