# eclipse's "open resource" slow when using a working set

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I recently changed my working sets for the "open resource" screen because I was sick of seeing multiple versions of the same file due to my maven configuration (a class in a child pom would show up under child and parent projects).  I used the advice from a stack overflow question:

[Eclipse Maven showing multiple paths for the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797438/eclipse-maven-showing-multiple-paths-for-the-same-file)

This does work.  However, it also causes a noticeable lag when I try to use open resources.  Any resource that is currently open will be available to search immediately, but if a resource is not yet open I will have to wait a decent length of time for the resource to be populated.  The lag is worse then just dealing with duplicate files.

Is there a reason for this noticeable lag?  I am running on a computer with limited resources, it's particularly IO bound, but the regular open resources without a specific working set is effectively instantaneous.  Is there some caching going on, and if so can I make eclipse cache the working-set's resources?

Comment: Same problem here. Its ridiculously slow, even though it should be faster with a restricted working set.

Comment: This is happening with Eclipse 2019-6. Deselect a working set and it's fast again.