# Enable Ctrl+click in "duplicated" files - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-luna

I have a **Maven** project in **Eclipse** and some files appear twice at searching.

Because I have a lot of folders & projects, the approach that is described here ([Eclipse file search finds the same file multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064796/eclipse-file-search-finds-the-same-file-multiple-times)) is not a solution - I can't "ignore" all folders manually.

I have 2 problems, but the second one is more important:

1) Some files have **duplicates** when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (Open Resource), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (File Search), etc. because Eclipse thinks that they are in 2 locations:

- B/path/resource
- A/B/path/resource

2) If I open:

- B/path/resource -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click works in this file
- A/B/path/resource -> **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click doesn't work** in this file

How can I solve the second problem?

It's acceptable to have duplicates, but it's difficult to work with duplicates that are not quite duplicates.

---

**Details**:

- O.S.: Windows 7
- IDE: Eclipse Luna (4.4)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click = Open Declaration = <kbd>F3</kbd> (it also doesn't work)

  - works = the wanted resource is opened (the links work)
  - doesn't work = the wanted resource is not opened (the links don't work)
- The problem appear for all files (E.g.: Java, XML: application-context.xml)

Comment: When you have Open Resource open and click the Down arrow on the top right, does that have "Show Derived Resources" checked? I don't know how to solve your issue but working through what it isn't may help us find what it is.

Comment: "Show Derived Resources" is unchecked, but I don't think that derived resources are a solution for me because I don't know to exist an option like "consider all resources that have duplicates as derived".

Comment: What are you expecting "ctrl-click" to do, and what does "work" or "doesn't work" mean?  What kinds of files are these that you're opening, and what are the multiple paths you see?